# How to use findElements for img class?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

On inspect element I can see number of records is 15 but when I tried using `findelements` it does not show all records.
Below is the tag:

```
<img class="md-user-avatar" ng-src="/../../resources/image_thumb.png" src="/../../resources/image4_thumb.png">
```

And I am using as below:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@class='md-user-avatar']"));
System.out.println("Number of elements:" +elements.size());
for (int i=0; i<elements.size();i++){
    System.out.println("Radio button text:" + elements.get(i).getAttribute("value"));
}
```

But it returns me size as 1. And when I fire `//img[@class='md-user-avatar']` in inspect elements it shows me 15 records.

Comment: Can you see all 15 images without doing scroll down ? What is the output of `System.out.println("Number of elements:" +elements.size());` line ?

Comment: no output. It just prints size as 1

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: sorry but  cant. what else you need?

Comment: Show html code.

Comment: How do you do it manually ? Can you see all 15 elements in your viewport ? or Is there any mouse or Keyboard interaction you do in order to see all 15 elements

Comment: it's likely you need to use a webdriverwait, but be aware that findElements will return if at least 1 element is found.  Either catch stale element errors and re-get array, or add a long enough sleep before using findElements call.

Answer (score 0):

try adding some implicit wait or Thread.sleep before doing `findElements`and see if it works. If it does, then you will have to use explicit waits to make sure all images have loaded.

And if it doesn't, then in that case you will have to see that how all 15 images are visible manually.